# Is there a way to remove a space after calling an input in a print statement?

Tags: python-3.x

How may I write the following code differently in order to have no space after input 'friend' and before text '!!!' in the first print statement? Code Reference: *print('Happy New Year', friend, '!!!')*

```
friends = ['Friend1', 'Friend2', 'Friend3', 'Friend4']
for friend in friends :
    print('Happy New Year', friend, '!!!')
print('Done!')
```

Comment: [Formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) string is straightforward `print(f'Happy New Year {friend}!!!')`

Comment: I haven't learned about that yet, and thank you.

Comment: Python 3.x `print` has parameters `print(value, ..., sep = ' ', end = '\n', file = sys.stdout, flush = False)`. Try making `sep = ''`.